# Importing CSV file to android sqlite datase on phone itself

Tags: android, sqlite, csv, import

I am trying to import a CSV file into android database. I tried inserting the csv file line by line ( `myDB.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, values)` command), but it was very slow.

One of the alternatives provided on net was to convert csv to sqlite on computer itself, and then copy it.

But the app requires to import csv files only, and I have seen apps on Google-play that do the same pretty fast.

Also the CSV table is not static so storing it in assets folder and importing is not an option. And, somewhere it was mentioned that Insert Helper is deprecated from version 17, so probably it should also not be used.

Please Help.

Comment: This is a [FAQ](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q19).

Comment: @CL. could you please tell a link, as I was unable to find any solution.

Comment: The answer tells you to use a single transaction.